# error: LICENSE not set to 'accept' with DB2 at Docker

Tags: database, docker

I followed the instructions at https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2 and pulled db2 image on my maschine. The docker run command fails with:

> error: LICENSE not set to 'accept' 
>   Please set '-e LICENSE=accept' to accept License before use the DB2 software contained in this image.

I have an .env_list that provides correctly this variable. If I use -e LICENSE=accept directly in console like so:

> docker run ibmcom/db2 -itd --name DB2_TEST --privileged=true -p
>   50000:50000 -e LICENSE=accept -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=INSTPW -e
>   DBNAME=testdb -v C:/DOCKER/db2/persistance_testdb

I will get this Error too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `docker run`, the instructions are

```
Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

which means all the options has to be before `IMAGE` and in your case `it` is appearing after `IMAGE`.

The correct command should be

```
docker run -itd --name DB2_TEST --privileged=true -p 50000:50000 -e LICENSE=accept -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=INSTPW -e DBNAME=testdb -v C:/DOCKER/db2/persistance_testdb:/database ibmcom/db2
```

Comment: Did it work? Can you accept as answer so that we close this?

Comment: Sorry.... much too late but i accept the answer and will make it better in future.